# VS 2015 Update 3 Internal compiler Error when curiously recursive template pattern with name hiding is used

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-bug

Here is a small,standalone use case that I am trying to compile using `VS2015 Update 3` compiler.

```
template <typename Derived, typename SomeType> class BaseClass
{
public:        
    void NameHidingMethod(SomeType const & node) 
    {
        // Do Something
    }
};

namespace structured {
    typedef struct _Structure
    {
    } Structure;
    template <typename Derived> 
      using BaseClass = BaseClass<Derived, Structure>;
}

class DerivedClass : public structured::BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    public:
        using structured::BaseClass<DerivedClass>::NameHidingMethod; // Generates error
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine on VS 2013 but fails VS 2015 Update 3. Here is the error message that I get.

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\symbols.c', line 5786)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Is my code legit ? If yes, then what could be a possible workaround ?

Comment: At first sight; this all looks fine; though; I would write: `struct Structure {};` instead. When trying to compile with clang (see https://godbolt.org/g/qG9thr), it gets accepted; so I suggest you at least contact the Technical Support.
That said, you might want to implement a forwarding method instead. (see https://godbolt.org/g/eRU12D)

Comment: Filed a [relevant bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3118530).